# how to implement <> operator feature of Java 7 with Java 6

Tags: java, generics

we know that the type earser, the generics are earsed and we will have only the Object type in the compiled code.

I want to understand how the diamond operator is implemented in java 7.

Comment: It is not an operator - it is syntax for omitted type parameters. You cannot do this in Java 6 in a type-safe way.

Comment: Some notes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512526/java-7-diamond-operator-why-was-it-difficult-to-implement

Comment: The types are still erased. The diamond operator simply makes the code more readable by inferring generic types so you don't have to type them again when calling constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The diamond operator is a **compiler** feature. I.e. you have to check the `javac` for details. All that happens is that the compiler can infer the generic types for you in some cases. Say for instance, it works with `List<String> = new ArrayList<>()`. On the other hand, it will not work with anonymous inner classes.

You will get the same exact byte code as without diamond operator. You can say that this is a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

So, how to implement it in java 6? Unfortunately, you **don't**. There is no operator overloading in java.

You can write some sort of wrappers, but I don't think it's worth the trouble:

```
public static <T> List<T> createArrayList(Class<T> typeClass) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}

List<String> list = createArrayList(String.class);
```